# Can I disable the emacs wanderlust splash screen?

Tags: emacs, startup

I have searched the wanderlust docs for all the keywords I could think of, to no avail.

When I start wanderlust, there is a very ugly splash screen while the program initializes. Can I disable that somehow? Emacs hangs for about a second *after* that splash screen has gone anyway, so I would prefer it to hang for two seconds instead and not show the splash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this library, but IIUC you're looking for this:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `wl-demo` <kbd>RET</kbd>